# How to blend two image using Poisson blending and CLM in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, blending

I have two images. I use one image as a source image and another one as destination image. In the source image I cropped a region of interest and that cropped region should be blended in the destination image so the output will look like Poisson blending. The code I have used up to this step is as [Code_for_Poisson_blending](https://jayabalaji1394.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/code-for-poisson-blend/)

Here the region size remains constant; therefore, it is not working for dissimilar image sizes. I want to move to Constrained_local_model (CLM) to detect the points in the region and mask this to the destination image.

My question is: how can I blend the selected region in the source image using CLM and to mask it with the destination image?